# Problems with passing objects in tree structure

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, object-oriented

I'm new to C++ and arduino. I want to build an object Tree, but it did not behave like I expected. Here is the code:

TreeNode.h

```
class TreeNode {

  public:
    TreeNode(String inputNodeName);
    TreeNode *children[];
    TreeNode &getChild(int index);
    int getLength();
    String nodeName;
    void addChild(TreeNode &node);
    String getName();

  private:
    int childLength;
};
```

TreeNode.cpp

```
  TreeNode::TreeNode(String inputNodeName) {
    nodeName = inputNodeName;
    childLength = 0;
  }

  TreeNode &TreeNode::getChild(int index) {
    return *children[index];
  }

  int TreeNode::getLength() {
    return childLength;
  }

  String TreeNode::getName(){
    return nodeName.c_str();
  }

  void TreeNode::addChild(TreeNode &node) {
    children[childLength] = &node;
    childLength++;
  }
```

I'm initialising it in the setup function:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    TreeNode mainTree("main");
    TreeNode firstChild("first child");
    TreeNode secondChild("second child");
    TreeNode subChild("subschild");

    Serial.println(mainTree.getName()); //prints "main"
    Serial.println(firstChild.getName()); //prints "first child";
    Serial.println(secondChild.getName()); //prints second child";

    mainTree.addChild(firstChild);
    mainTree.addChild(secondChild);
    Serial.println(mainTree.getName()); // prints an empty string
    Serial.println(secondChild.getName()); //prints second child"

    secondChild.addChild(subChild);
    Serial.println(secondChild.getName()); //prints an empty string
}
```

So my problem is, when I'm adding a child to a node, the node name is empty, or strange characters will be displayed.
I think I misunderstood passing an object by reference. Can anybody explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Arrays do not expand like in Java or Basic. You need to allocate a specific number of entries, or use a *linked list* or C++ STL wrapper object like vector.

Comment: Here we go - I have just drafted a blog entry on C arrays: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/arrays-pointers-what-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TreeNode *children[];
```

That declares an array of pointers however it also requires that you assign memory to it. I never see you allocate that memory.

If you only expect a small amount of children then you can use that upper bound as a static allocation:

```
#define MAX_CHILDREN 10

//...
TreeNode *children[MAX_CHILDREN];
```

Otherwise use a vector instead:

```
std::vector<TreeNode *> children;
```